# How to find precision of float if n bits are corrupt or lost

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I am currently solving a sparse linear system with the sparse solver from scipy, Python.

I am comparing an analytical solution to the result of the simulated solution. However, in some regime, I have got some doubts as to the precision of the simulated result.

It is quite hard to estimate the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) for sparse matrices. I can find the largest eigenvalue of the matrix, but the search for the smallest eigenvalue never converges, so I cannot even use max(eig)/min(eig) = condition. 
Going with another approximation, which is max(abs(diag))/min(abs(diag)), I get a condition number of which the log2 gives 26, so I am heuristically speaking losing about 26 bits of precision on my result.

My question is the following : given that my computation is done with [float64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (numpy), and 26 bits are missing, how can I compute know which decimals of my number I can trust ? 
For example, if the answer given by my simulation is :

Number_to_verify = 1663.123609834 (float64)
and the 26 last bits are potentially corrupt, what part of this number can I trust ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, `float64` have 52 bits of mantissa and ~ 16 significative decimal digits.
so if you are sure that 26 bits are corrupted, conserve 8 decimal digits.

more precisely the error is about `Number_to_ verify * 2**(-26) # 2e-05`.

A technical approach to valid that :

```
f=1663.123609834
num,den=f.as_integer_ratio()
p=2**26
ninf=n//p*p
nsup=ninf|(p-1)
print(bin(ninf),bin(n),bin(nsup),sep='\n')
print(ninf/d,n/d,nsup/d,sep='\n')
```

For

```
##12345678901234567890123456 12345678901234567890123456
0b11001111111000111111010010 00000000000000000000000000
0b11001111111000111111010010 01110010011100010011111101
0b11001111111000111111010010 11111111111111111111111111

1663.1235961914062
1663.123609834
1663.123626708984
```